# MvvmCross ViewModels not destroyed on FragmentManager.PopBackstackImmediate()

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have built a Xamarin Android app that presents the user with a series of data entry forms, like a wizard. The wizard has a bottom navigation bar with previous and next buttons, and a menu button that when pressed displays a list of all forms in the wizard and allows the user to jump to any given form. 
The desired functionality is to preserve the linear navigation, so that when the user jumps to the middle of the wizard, they can still use the previous and next buttons to page through the various forms in order. They should also be able to use the hardware back button to view the previous form in the wizard. 
I suspect my implementation is not MvvmCross friendly because I'm seeing some bugs with it, specifically my viewmodels are not destroyed when I clear the fragment backstack (wizard hosted in an Activity, each form is a Fragment).

How should I implement this?

Comment: how are you clearing the fragment backstack? Each time the user taps back button or uses the navigation bar buttons do you explicitly navigate to the corresponding ViewModel?

Comment: Linear navigation (previous and next) is done conventionally, by using the navigation service API to show or close a viewmodel. This error only presents itself when I am trying to manipulate the backstack, either to clear it or to preload a fragment stack, say if they're resuming the wizard after having partially completed it. For that I am using the Activity.SupportFragmentManager.PopBackstackImmediate() method. I'm investigating iterating over the fragments to close each one to see if that fixes this error. I'm fighting with casting right now.

Comment: Iterating over the fragments and closing them one by one does not change this behavior. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong or have misdiagnosed the cause of these viewmodels being reused.

Comment: I've now had to resort to pulling in the MvxAndroidViewPresenter source to get a peek at what's going on under the hood in the hopes that this will give me a lead. I gotta be honest, Mvvm Cross support really sucks. Maybe I'm not asking the question right, but I had hoped someone with knowledge would understand my intent and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be something unconventional about my implementation, but with a deadline and little help from the community, what do you do to fix your hack, but to hack it more?

My solution was twofold: 
1) instead of using FragmentManager.PopBackstackImmediate(), I implemented a while loop with the condition: activity.SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 0, calling Close(fragment.ViewModel) in the body. This should have fixed the bug, but it didn't. 
2) The ViewModels I was requesting to Close were still not being disposed, so I had to resolve the current IMvxMultipleViewModelCache and call GetAndClear on it with the expected parameters. This forced my ViewModels to be disposed so they will be recreated on the next viewing of its Fragment.

This feels like a hack. Closing a ViewModel should dispose of it whether it's associated with a Fragment or Activity, but for some reason it wasn't. That's the key to this bug, but like I said, deadline, hack on hack.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.FragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate/p/System.String/Android.App.PopBackStackFlags/) overload of `PopBackStackImmediate`? This one will pop all of the fragments until the one you specify in the string (if inclusive flag is passed, then that fragment is also popped) so you spare iterating all over the fragment backstack.

```
Activity.SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate("myViewTag", (int)PopBackStackFlags.Inclusive);
```

where `"myViewTag"` is the `UniqueImmutableCacheTag` of your View

Comment: That behaves the same way. I suspect this is less an Android question and more an MvvmCross question. PopBackStackImmediate() and its overloads all result in the ViewModels associated with those Fragments not being destroyed, and reattached the next time that fragment is viewed. The result is incorrect DataContext.